# InsertionSort Descending order java

Tags: java, sorting, insertion-sort

This is the code for doing an insertionSort in ascending order. I'm trying to change the code so it can do descending order. But every time I change something it gets worse. Could someone point me in the right direction?

```
public static void insertionSort(Comparable[] list)
{
  for (int index = 0; index < list.length; index++)
  {
     Comparable key = list[index];
     int position = index;

     //  Shift larger values to the right
     while (position > 0 && key.compareTo(list[position-1]) < 0)
     {
        list[position] = list[position-1];
        position--;
     }

     list[position] = key;
  }
}
```

Comment: What you do and what gets worse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current `insertionSort()` function's code is correct for sorting in ascending order. This is a good baseline to start with.

I don't know what changes you tried in order to make a descending order version. Please include that information next time, because we otherwise we can't tell you why it didn't work.

To change your function to sort descending, literally change a single character:

```
// Sort-ascending version (current)
key.compareTo(list[position-1]) < 0

// Sort-descending version (proposed
key.compareTo(list[position-1]) > 0
```

I have tested this change and confirmed it works. Hope this helps!

Comment: wow that was too easy, i was thinking too complex and trying to change condition for the while loop and the less than sign instead of just one, but thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any big problems with your code. What I would do is I would overload this function with one taking an additional parameter: a `Comparator` ([docs here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)) which is used in place of the natural `compareTo`.

As an inspiration look at the [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) (Collections in java)

> `static <T> void  sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c)` Sorts the
>   specified list according to the order induced by the specified
>   comparator.

To obtain descending order you can call your function with something like the following:

```
insertionSort(A,
                new Comparator<Integer>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
                return o2.compareTo(o1) ;
            }}
        );
```

Comment: Your comparator needs a case for +1. Easiest fix is to `return o2.compareTo(o1);`.